# xQuery, how to get text from node with childs?

Tags: xml, text, xquery, xmlnode

This line:

```
//div[@id="transactions"]/p
```

gives this output (from html content I'm trying to get):

[image]

How can i make this query return a string like this (the content if each `<p>` in it's own line):

```
contentOfP1
contentOfP2
contentOfP3
...
```

Notice that each p have child nodes (`<strong>` and `<a>`) and text with no tags. when trying to retrieve all text from a specific `<p>`, it gives this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use**:

```
//div[@id="transactions"]/p/concat(string(.), '&#xA;')
```

Or, if the space-normalized "content of each paragraph" is wanted -- as indicated in a comment, use:

```
//div[@id="transactions"]/p/concat(normalize-space(.), '&#xA;')
```

Comment: Your answer almost made me cry :(
I wasted hours looking for an answer, and it was that simple !
Thanks a lot <3

Comment: Well, It doesnt work. But I finally got what I want using `for $p in ($doc//div[@id="transactions"]/p)          return concat(normalize-space(string($p)), '&#xA;')` thanks to you :)

Comment: @Batis610: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? I am glad that this answer was useful to you. Would you, please then *accept* it (by clicking on the check-mark next to the answer)?

Comment: It just didnt give me the expected output. But indeed your answer helped a lot.
I'm new here, apologies if I didnt accept the answer before :)

Comment: @Batis610: You are welcome. Just a note that a `for` clause isn't necessary -- I think that the second expression in the updated answer produces what you probably want.

Comment: Indeed, the second expression give me the same result as the `for`. Thanks again :-)

Comment: @Enissay: This is a subject for a new, separate question -- it is an essential question -- the second most FAQ in XPath. I can give you the answer immediately, but the comments format isn't convenient for sharing code. Also, it is bad for everyone to have a question with N updates where N -> Infinity. Please, ask a new question and notify me via a comment -- I will be glad to answer.